# A problem with logarithmic differentiation

Tags: derivatives

I'm solving a problem to find if h(x) = (a^|x|)*sgn(x) is increasing or decreasing (taking a>1) for all real values of x.                                                                        For x>0 and for x=0, I have found that f'(x) >= 0.. But for x<0, h(x)=-(a^{-x}) and I can't figure out how to differentiate this.. If I apply logarithmic differentiation I get log(h(x))= (-x)*(log(-a)) and already I have log of a negative number.. How do I differentiate this now?      When I graph h(x) for x<0, I can see that it is differentiable, but I can't figure out its derivative..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. You have
$$
h(x)=-a^{-x}, \quad x<0,
$$ if you write it as
$$
h(x)=-e^{-x \ln a}, \quad x<0,
$$ maybe it becomes easier to apply the chain rule:
$$
\left(e^{u(x)} \right)'=u'(x)\cdot e^{u(x)}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Now i understand it much better :)